# Why rewrite to index.php is not working on a wordpress site?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So my rewriterule is like

```
RewriteRule ^test$ index.php [L]
```

I tested it on https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=b0a9904b-1ec4-49cd-917c-36426ff6150a it works fine.

[image]

I also tested it on live Joomla sites and on a HTML sites, it all work fine.

However, when I try to test this on a Wordpress site, I am always getting a 404 page.
By default, wordpress site's .htaccess file is like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I add my rewrite rule above to the first line, but when I open mysite.com/test I will get a 404 error.

To test, I create a `1.php` file and modify my rule to

```
RewriteRule ^test$ 1.php [L]
```

This time, when I open mysite.com/test it successfully executes `1.php`. So the catch here is `index.php`.

What I don't understand is if I open mysite.com/index.php it will load mysite.com without problem. And I believe

```
RewriteRule ^test$ index.php [L]
```

in essential is telling the server when user request mysite.com/test show him mysite.com/index.php, then why in actuality I am getting a 404 page(not a blank 404, but the 404 page handled by wordpress's theme) when trying to open mysite.com/test?

P.S. I've also tried removing the default wordpress rules, but still getting the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am getting a 404 page(not a blank 404, but the **404 page handled by wordpress's theme**)

Your rule is successfully rewriting the request to `index.php`, however...

`index.php` is the WordPress front-controller. Code in this file looks at the requested URL (eg. `/test` in your example) and decides how to handle it. If `/test` is not a valid route defined in WordPress then WordPress (not Apache) generates a 404. This isn't reporting that the file `index.php` does not exist, but that the URL `/test` does not exist inside of WordPress, ie. there is no route defined for this URL in WordPress.

> I add my rewrite rule above to the first line

**UPDATE:** Incidentally, unless `/test` maps to an existing directory (or file) then the WordPress code block already does exactly what you are doing with the rewrite... it rewrites the request to `/index.php` with the last rule.

So, the directive you are adding is in fact entirely superfluous anyway.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^test$ 1.php [L]
> ```

If the code in `1.php` responds with a 404 (for whatever reason), then this would also result in a 404.

Comment: So although Apache rewrites the URL it still passes the original request (in my case /test) to Wordpress? And how then do I rewrite /test to /?

Comment: @WenShenk Yes, the original request is available to PHP (ie. WordPress) in the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal - and WP uses this to route the URL through the CMS. Incidentally, your rewrite is really superfluous (assuming `/test` does not map to a file or directory) since the WordPress code block already rewrites the request to `/index.php` in the last rule.

Comment: @WenShenk "how then do I rewrite /test to /?" - Do you mean "redirect"? It doesn't make sense to internally rewrite `/test` to `/`. `/` itself is not a valid end-point. It would require further rewriting to handle the request (eg. to serve the `DirectoryIndex`). However, unless you are implementing an additional app outside of WordPress then all URLs/routing need to be configured in WordPress itself - not `.htaccess`. AFAIK, WordPress itself does not provide a mechanism to "rewrite" requests outside of WP itself, unlike some other CMS, since it always looks that the URL the user requested.

Comment: What I actually wanna do is redirect myurl.com/shop to the homepage - I don't want woocommerce's shop page to be available to users. Well, maybe I should ask this in Wordpress forum, but I am still not quite sure if this is a Wordpress issue or mod_rewrite issue.

Comment: @WenShenk Ok, so what is the problem you are having when you redirect `/shop` to the homepage?

Comment: The problem is I am not sure what is the right way to redirect `/shop` to the homepage. Because when I try `RewriteRule ^shop$ index.php [L]` it will still go to the shop page. Actually even `RewriteRule ^shop$ https://google.com [L]` for testing purpose won't work. So I guess mod_rewrite is not the right way to do this.

Comment: @WenShenk To "redirect" you would need to use `RewriteRule ^shop$ / [R=302,L]` if `/shop` is the only URL, or `^shop($|/)` for any URL that _starts_ `/shop`. And this would need to go at the very top of the `.htaccess` file, at least _before_ the WordPress code block. What do you mean by "for testing purpose won't work"? Does nothing happen? Or something else? However, this would seem to be unrelated to your initial question. (?)

Comment: What I am trying to say is it seems any rewrite rule won't have effect on `/shop`, though it may work with any other URL that is not registered with wordpress. Maybe a video is easier to demonstrate: https://www.loom.com/share/caf60e8b5a5343d3b62b2f87e4d6ca94

Comment: @WenShenk (Not sure that that video really clarifies anything?) `RewriteRule ^shop$ / [R=302,L]` should work, unless... `/shop` is a physical directory that contains its own `.htaccess` file or `/shop` is not that actual URL being requested. As mentioned, you'd probably need to match `^shop($|/)`, not just `^shop$`. Also make sure you are not seeing a cached response.

Comment: On the video you should be able to see `RewriteRule ^shop$ / [R=302,L]` is not working, and there is no such physical directory on my server. In case you don't know, `/shop` is registered by woocommerce as the Shop page. I think that's why the rewrite rule is not working on this particular URL. And yes, this is a little off-topic, maybe I should start another post in wordpress's forum. But I really appreciate your help here.

Comment: @WenShenk (Ah, the video had not fully loaded before - just the first few seconds kept repeating!) However, the URL in the browser is `/shop/` (with a trailing slash), not `/shop` (the URL you are checking for). Where is `/shop/` (trailing slash) coming from? Is this completed by the browser? Check the network traffic in the browser devtools.

Comment: I think the slash is added by wordpress/woocommerce

Comment: @WenShenk "`/shop` is registered by woocommerce as the Shop page. I think that's why the rewrite rule is not working on this particular URL." - the rule (redirect) at the top of the `.htaccess` file is processed _before_ WordPress/WooCommerce or PHP itself are even started so this has nothing to do with `/shop` being a registered URL by WooCommerce.

Comment: @WenShenk I just tried the `/shop` URL on your site and I'm 302 redirected to `google.com`, so unless you've changed something, you're probably seeing a cached response/redirect (as mentioned above).

Comment: Thank you so much. Wasn't aware this could be cached.